# Random number from column

Tags: python, pandas

The goal is to fill the nan values in a column with a random number chosen from that same column.

I can do this one column as a time but when iterating through all the columns in the data frame I get a variety of errors. When I use "random.choice" I get letters rather than column values.

```
 df1 = df_na
 df2 = df_nan.dropna()

 for i in range(5):
    for j in range(len(df1)):
        if np.isnan(df1.iloc[j,i]):
           df1.iloc[j,i] = np.random.choice(df2.columns[i])

 df1
```

Any suggestions on how to move forward?

Comment: Please add a small sample input and the corresponding expected output

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
# sample data
df =pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,None,18,20,None],
                  'b': [22,33,44,None,100,32]})

# fill missing with a random value from that column
for col in df.columns:
    df[col].fillna(df[col].dropna().sample().values[0], inplace=True)

      a      b
0   1.0     22.0
1   2.0     33.0
2   20.0    44.0
3   18.0    100.0
4   20.0    100.0
5   20.0    32.0
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly! This approach is different than others I have seen so it was helpful and informative.

Comment: Follow up question. This method made is so that all nan values in a given column were replaced by the same values. Is there a method so that each each row of a column is treated independently and a new random sample is taken to fill each individual nan value?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`np.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```
df = df.apply(lambda s: s.fillna(np.random.choice(s.dropna())))
```

Comment: This worked and it using the same .apply function I was trying to use originally. I was getting errors when trying to iterate through columns using the for loop. Thank you for the insight!

Comment: One more question, is "s" referencing data frame df? Will the variable also reference the data frame? For example in:  

     speeds_df.apply(lambda sp: sp.fillna(0))

Will sp reference data frame speeds_df?

Comment: I've used `s` to stand for "series", it represents each column, you can choose any letter you like though.

Comment: Follow up question. This method made is so that all nan values in a given column were replaced by the same values. Is there a method so that each each row of a column is treated independently and a new random sample is taken to fill each individual nan value?

Comment: @Dee, Probably, but that's a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) which you should ask separately. If an answer here solves your original problem, do accept it (tick on left) so other users know.